# Kinetic JS show border on Image after changing color

Tags: kineticjs

Has anyone else noticed this, or found a solution?
Let's say I have an image.

```
       image.setAttrs({
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 0,
            lineJoin: 'round',
            dash: [ 5, 5 ],
            dashEnabled: true,
            strokeEnabled: true 
        });

        image.draw();
```

This works fine, and my image is drawn with a square dashed border.
Now let's recolor the image:

```
        image.cache();

        image.filters([Kinetic.Filters.RGB]);
        image.red(r).green(g).blue(b);

        image.draw();
```

Now the image is recolored, but the stroke is lost. I can't seem to find any way to make it reappear.

If I check the object using console.dir(), the attribute "strokeEnabled" shows as "true".

Comment: Do you have any demo? This example works fine: http://jsbin.com/ferig/1/edit

Comment: Yes. Here is a working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/PhJx9/8/

Comment: And yours is working because you cached it. The process of 'caching' converts whatever is on the stage to an image, even the border. Now you can't turn that border off ever. It's not a border really, it's a bitmap image. In my demo above, turn the border ON, then click the image. Now you have a permanent border that you can't turn off.

Comment: UPDATE: It does work if you turn the border ON, then drag the shape. But I don't know why you have to drag it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear cache before using `stokeEnabled`.

```
myImage.clearCache();
myImage.strokeEnabled(true);
myImage.cache({
    x : myImage.x() - 2,
    y : myImage.y() - 2,
    width : myImage.width() + 4,
    height : myImage.height() + 4
});
myStage.draw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhJx9/23/

Comment: Again, thanks! Project moving forward lightspeed now.